# NullPointerException on spring autowiring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I wrote a practice problem for Spring autowiring and getting `NullPointerException`.

here is my code
 **interface: Shape**

```
public interface Shape {
    public void draw();
}
```

**Class : Triangle**

```
    public class Triangle implements Shape{

    private Point A;
    private Point B;
    private Point C;

    public Point getA() {
        return A;
    }

    public void setA(Point a) {
        A = a;
    }

    public Point getB() {
        return B;
    }

    public void setB(Point b) {
        B = b;
    }

    public Point getC() {
        return C;
    }

    public void setC(Point c) {
        C = c;
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("PointA("+ A.getX() + "," + A.getY() +")");
        System.out.println("PointB("+ B.getX() + "," + B.getY() +")");
        System.out.println("PointC("+ C.getX() + "," + C.getY() +")");
    }
}
```

**Class : Points**

```
public class Point {

    private int x,y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

**Spring XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="triangle" class="org.demo.javabrains.Triangle" autowire="byName">
    </bean>

    <bean id="A" class="org.demo.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0"/>
        <property name="y" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="B" class="org.demo.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value="10"/>
        <property name="y" value="20"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="C" class="org.demo.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value="30"/>
        <property name="y" value="40"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Main Class**

```
public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Shape triangle =(Shape) context.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();

    }

}
```

I don't know why am I getting NullPointer Exception on this
when I try to run this code it throws exception

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.demo.javabrains.Triangle.draw(Triangle.java:34)
    at org.demo.javabrains.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:16)
```

Point A is assigned with value null don't know why

Comment: It's a simple typo: It should be `<bean id="a"` (lowercase), the same for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using *Autowiring by Property Name*:

```
<bean id="triangle" class="org.demo.javabrains.Triangle" autowire="byName" />
```

Spring looks for a bean with the same name as the property that needs to be autowired. For example, if a bean definition is set to autowire `byName`, and it contains a property named `a`, i.e. it has a `setA(..)` method (Not to be confused with a field named `A`) , Spring looks for a bean definition named `a` , and uses it to set the property.

As @Tunaki correctly pointed out in comments, you're confusing property names with name of the field itself which is `A`. Anyway if you use lowercase names for your `Point` beans, you would be fine:

```
<bean id="a" class="org.demo.javabrains.Point"> /* Same as before */ </bean>

<bean id="b" class="org.demo.javabrains.Point"> /* Same as before */ </bean>

<bean id="c" class="org.demo.javabrains.Point"> /* Same as before */ </bean>
```

For more detailed discussion about Autowiring collaborators in Spring, checkout the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-autowire).

Answer (score 0):

Your **Triangle**.draw() method uses Point class object. You had declared Point object in xml but did't use it to inject into triangle bean definition. That's why it's giving null pointer exception cause it's not initialise.

Your triangle bean def in Spring XML should be like

```
<bean id="triangle" class="org.demo.javabrains.Triangle" autowire="byName">
 <property name="A" ref="A"/>
 <property name="B" ref="B"/>
 <property name="B" ref="B"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use Uppercase to the bean name(the first word), also try not to set the object variable starting with Uppercase, this will cause null pointer exceptions.

```
//These are the bean definitions
<bean name="MyClassA" id="Aclass" class="com.test.autowire.MyClassA" autowire="byName"></bean>
<bean name="bClass" id="bClass" class="com.test.autowire.MyClassB"></bean>



public class MyClassA {
private MyClassB bClass; 
//donot use BClass, use the first letter as lowercase eg: bClass

public MyClassB getbClass() {
    return bClass;
}

public void setbClass(MyClassB bClass) {
    this.bClass = bClass;
}

public void printInA(){
    bClass.print();
    bClass.disp();
}
}

public class MyClassB {
MyClassB(){
    System.out.println("THis is my Class B default Constrctr");
}
void print(){
    System.out.println("This is a print");
}
void disp(){
    System.out.println("This is disp methd");
}
}
```